# How can I publish all the items that link to a particular item?

Tags: publishing

I am using Sitecore 9.1

I recently deleted an item (let's call it A) and selected `Link to another Item` when presented with the Breaking Links dialog, redirecting these links to a new item (B). This means that items C and D now point to B instead of A. When I publish B and select `publish related items`, items C and D are not published... According to the Sitecore Documentation I have read, this seems to be because items that *B links to* are considered related, but not items that *link to B.* Is there a way to easily publish all the items that link to B or do I have to do this manually? (In my example there are only 2 items linking to B, but in fact, there are closer to 60, so publishing them manually is going to be hard.)

Comment: you can try publish related items as well in publishing dialog box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Sitecore Powershell Extensions to achieve what you need.

You first need to call `Get-ItemReferrer` function and then `Publish-Item` on every item you get from the first function.

```
$linkedItemId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}"
$itemsLinkingToMyItem = Get-ItemReferrer -Path $linkedItemId

foreach ($itemLinkingToMyItem in $itemsLinkingToMyItem) {
    Publish-Item -Item $itemLinkingToMyItem
}
```

Source:

https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-publish-all-items-linking-to-an-item

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "Publish Item" with both "Republish" and "Publish related items" together if I understood you properly:

[image]

Also make sure, that C and D are in the Final workflow state and have no publishing restrictions and the link database is up-to-date.

As an alternative, you can use SPE script or the custom patches similar to: https://abarhoum.wordpress.com/2016/08/29/deep-publishing-of-related-items-with-sitecroe-experience-editor/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this didn't work for me, even doing a republish instead of a smart publish. It looks like, for some reason, Sitecore doesn't consider items linking to the current item to be related. The only way I managed to get this to work was by replicating the change in Web manually.

Comment: @ajrskelton Usually, Sitecore uses Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.AddItemReferences pipeline processor, which is using getItemReferences pipeline that probably should add related items. Make sure that you have rebuilt the link database. You can patch this processor mentioned above or use Sitecore Powershell Extension (https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemreferrer, https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemreference, and https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/publish-item) as an alternative.